# Stitching Panoramic Images

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Today I came up with an interesting project from Germany: [Throwable PanoramicBall Camera](http://jonaspfeil.de/ballcamera)  36 images are captured in a small ball, then they are showed panoramically. The author declares to use OpenCV

Can you give me some idea about creating a model for cameras at fixed position/orientation and stitching images with OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Image rectification:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification

This book also has some good explanations and code examples on how to do it in OpenCV in the later chapters:
[http://www.amazon.com/OpenCV-Computer-Application-Programming-Cookbook/dp/1849513244/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1319209140&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513244)

Answer (score 0):

The author was probably using the new samples available in OpenCV.

Here are links to the samples currently available in OpenCV...

1. [stitching_detailed](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp)
2. [stitching](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp)

You may want to start with these samples if you're trying to do image stitching in OpenCV.

Comment: Both of your links require a login.

Comment: @JacobRobbins Thanks for catching that! I've updated the links from the old ROS repository to OpenCV's official dev site.